# Method that checks four edges of a ball one by one to see if it collided with a wall

Tags: java, if-statement, direction

Add a method to your code that checks each of the four edges of the ball one by one, checking if that edge has collided with the edge of the window. If so, it should change direction accordingly. For instance, if the ball was moving north-east (↗) and the top edge had hit the top of the screen, it would change the direction to south-east (↘) so that the ball would appear to bounce off the edge. (Remember that if the ball goes directly into a corner in a diagonal direction, two edges could hit at once, making it bounce straight back in the opposite diagonal direction.)

I am not sure how to get the four edges of an oval. I have the other 4 directions done (up, down, left, right) done but am not sure how to handle corners of the window.

```
public void move()
  {
   //direction right
   if(dir == 1)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x + 1,y);        
            if(x>425)
            {
                dir = 2;                           
            }
   }           
   //direction left
   if(dir == 2)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x - 1,y);          
            if(x<0)
            {
                dir = 1;
            }
   }           
   //direction down
   if(dir == 3)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x,y + 1);               
            if(y>425)
            {
                dir = 4;
            }
   }       
   //direction up
   if(dir == 4)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x ,y - 1);         
            if(y<0)
            {
                dir = 3;
            }
   }           
   //direction bottom right corner
   if(dir == 5)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x + 1,y + 1);                           
   }           
   //direction upper right corner
   if(dir == 6)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x + 1,y - 1);
   }       

   //direction bottom left corner
   if(dir == 7)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x - 1,y + 1);
   }       
   //direction upper left corner
   if(dir == 8)
   {
       int x = ball.getX();
       int y = ball.getY();
       ball.setLocation(x - 1,y - 1);      
   }
}
```

Finally, make sure to call this method whenever you move the ball. That way, after you move the ball 1 pixel in its current direction, you run the method to check if it has hit any edge, and change direction. At this point, your ball should move about the screen ricocheting as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think too much about it being an oval. For the purposes of this assignment, it might just as well be a box. The only difference between the case for corners compared to the case for an edge is that you need to distinguish between 4 outcomes:

1. You hit a horizontal and vertical wall: Change to the opposite direction of the diagonal movement.
2. You hit a horizontal wall: Keep the vertical direction and switch the horizontal to the opposite.
3. You hit a vertical wall: Keep the horizontal direction and switch the vertical to the opposite.
4. You hit no wall at all: Do nothing.

Furthermore, the instructions specifically recommend that you separate movement logic from the logic for changing direction. In your initial approach, you are doing both at once.

In my example, I introduce a method `changeDirection()` that only checks if any boundary is hit and then turns you around, but no actual movement is taking place. You still need to implement `move()` and take care of that, but you can just call this method and assume that the ball is heading towards the correct direction afterwards.

Also, the code becomes easier to understand once you introduce named constants to refer to the directions:

```
  private static final int RIGHT = 1;
  private static final int LEFT = 2;
  private static final int DOWN = 3;
  private static final int UP = 4;
  private static final int DOWN_RIGHT = 5;
  private static final int UP_RIGHT = 6;
  private static final int DOWN_LEFT = 7;
  private static final int UP_LEFT = 8;

  private static final int WIDTH = 425;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 425;

  public void changeDirection()
  {
    int x = ball.getX();
    int y = ball.getY();

    switch ( dir )
    {
      case RIGHT:
        if ( x >= WIDTH )
        {
          dir = LEFT;
        }
        break;
      case LEFT:
        if ( x <= 0 )
        {
          dir = RIGHT;
        }
        break;
      case DOWN:
        if ( y >= HEIGHT )
        {
          dir = UP;
        }
        break;
      case UP:
        if ( y <= 0 )
        {
          dir = DOWN;
        }
        break;
      case DOWN_RIGHT:
        if ( y >= HEIGHT )
        {
          if ( x >= WIDTH )
          {
            dir = UP_LEFT;
          }
          else
          {
            dir = UP_RIGHT;
          }
        }
        else if ( x >= WIDTH )
        {
          dir = DOWN_LEFT;
        }
        break;
      case UP_RIGHT:
        if ( y <= 0 )
        {
          if ( x >= WIDTH )
          {
            dir = DOWN_LEFT;
          }
          else
          {
            dir = DOWN_RIGHT;
          }
        }
        else if ( x >= WIDTH )
        {
          dir = UP_LEFT;
        }
        break;
      case DOWN_LEFT:
        if ( y >= HEIGHT )
        {
          if ( x <= 0 )
          {
            dir = UP_RIGHT;
          }
          else
          {
            dir = UP_LEFT;
          }
        }
        else if ( x <= 0 )
        {
          dir = DOWN_RIGHT;
        }
        break;
      case UP_LEFT:
        if ( y <= 0 )
        {
          if ( x <= 0 )
          {
            dir = DOWN_RIGHT;
          }
          else
          {
            dir = UP_LEFT;
          }
        }
        else if ( x <= 0 )
        {
          dir = UP_RIGHT;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```